# Hibernate validator could not get value by key

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

My project use spring mvc and hibernate validator .And I am trying to make it support multi-language.
This is my spring-i18N file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>


    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="604800"/>
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="zh_CN" />
        <property name="cookieName" value="language"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:i18N/messages</value>
                <value>classpath:i18N/validation</value>
            </list>
        </property>
           <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
      <property name="providerClass" value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"/>
      <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And my problem is,while I use annotations in bean file,like this,

```
@Size(min=6, max=25,message="{password_length_require}")
private String password;
```

and in the validation_en_US.properties,I do this

```
password_length_require=The password length require more than 5 and less 25
```

The result is that page will output "{password_length_require} ".
On the other hand,in my controller,I use

```
bindingResult.rejectValue("password", "password_length_require");
```

It will work fine...

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before,it took me long time to solve it.
Just like me,there might be something wrong with the following configuration.

```
<property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:i18N/messages</value>
            <value>classpath:i18N/validation</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

The value of property "basenames" must be full path where your validation messages files save in your project.For example,if validation message files are in package named "org.example.config.i18N.messages", you should config the xml like this:

```
<value>classpath:org/example/config/i18N/messages</value>
```

So maybe you need to check whether or not your configuration is right.
The above is my experience, hope to help you.